# get x and y of image after pan and tilt camera

Tags: c++, opencv, math, computer-vision

I have a ptz camera looking at scene with initial pan and tilt values so the captured image (e.g. 1920x1080) will have a center (960,540) related to these initial values. Now after I change the pan/tilt values (move the camera), I want to compute the x,y coordinate of the new image center with respect to the initial image (i.e. if I panned 2 degree (to the right), the new image center is (960+x_offset, 540+y_offset). the y_offset is occurring because the pan axis is relative to the tilt axis. 
I tried to compute the true pan/tilt angles of the view (Z-rotation and Y-rotation) by forming the rotation matrix for the pan/tilt values then extract the angles from the rotation matrix using matrix-to-conversion formulas mentioned the code below. Then I use the FOV_X and FOV_Y to compute pixel-per-angle ratio. then I compute deltaX and deltaY based on the new angles.

However, I am still not getting the correct offset. I know it is wrong because I also implemented object detector that is located at (x,y) coordinate of the initial image which must match the same offset after moving the camera to make the object at the center of the image.

here is the code I am using

```
double phi = 0;
double theta =  (Params.Tilt - cameraCls->InitialTilt );
double psi = (Params.Pan - cameraCls->InitialPan);

Mat rotX = getRotationMatrix(theta*CV_PI / 180, 'X');
Mat rotY = getRotationMatrix(psi*CV_PI / 180, 'Z');
Mat rotZ = getRotationMatrix(phi*CV_PI / 180, 'X');

Mat rotationM = rotX * rotY * rotZ;

double t1 = atan2(-rotationM.at<double>(2, 0), rotationM.at<double>(0, 0)); 
double t2 = asin(rotationM.at<double>(1, 0)); 
double z_ang = atan2(-rotationM.at<double>(1, 2), rotationM.at<double>(1, 1));

// pixelHorAngle = ImgSize.width / FovX;
// pixelVertAngle = ImgSize.height / FovY;

double deltaX = cameraCls->pixelHorAngle *((t2 * 180 / CV_PI) );
double deltaY = cameraCls->pixelVertAngle *((z_ang * 180 / CV_PI) );
```

that's the getRotationMatrix function

```
Mat getRotationMatrix(double angle, char axis){
double vRot[3][3] = { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 };
Mat rot = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
switch (axis)
{
case 'X':
    rot.at<double>(1, 1) = cos(angle);
    rot.at<double>(1, 2) = -sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(2, 1) = sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(2, 2) = cos(angle);
    break;
case 'Y':
    rot.at<double>(0, 0) = cos(angle);
    rot.at<double>(0, 2) = sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(2, 0) = -sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(2, 2) = cos(angle);

    break;
case 'Z':
    rot.at<double>(0, 0) = cos(angle);
    rot.at<double>(0, 1) = -sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(1, 0) = sin(angle);
    rot.at<double>(1, 1) = cos(angle);

    break;
}

return rot;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that the real center can be detected by reading the camera parameters of after apply the calibration process for that camera. May be this is why your offset its wrong.

Comment: Yep I got all camera parameters and everything is relative to the calibrated center from the camera matrix

Comment: Mat `rotX` = getRotationMatrix(theta*CV_PI / 180, `'X'`);
Mat `rotY` = getRotationMatrix(psi*CV_PI / 180, `'Z'`);
Mat `rotZ` = getRotationMatrix(phi*CV_PI / 180, `'X'`); Are these correct?

Comment: you mean correct in the order of rotation or the axis of rotation or what?? I am suspecting this as well so I am not sure really

Comment: In two cases you have `X` as the second parameter of the `getRotationMatrix()` in `rotX` and `rotZ`, why? is this correct?

Comment: it is XZX rotation order, second parameter is the axis I am doing the rotation around. I edited my post to include the function